# Merging cells excel

Tags: excel, merge

I have a large number of spreadsheets of projects run by a company, and the amount the project earns in a year.

I am looking to combine these into one large spreadsheet, but many of the projects run over multiple years. Is there an easy way to merge the income columns of these duplicate values into one row?

i.e. instead of 4 projects with the same name but different incomes, one project with all 4 incomes listed.

Thanks

Comment: We are here to help, not to provide programming services. So try it on your own and come back with your code where you stuck

Answer (score 0):

If your spreadsheets have expressive names, then **yes**, probably with the help of some basic `VBA`.
Otherwise it is still easy but takes a lot of tedious work.